# Add BR tag when hitting ENTER (or Intro) php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a way to add the tag < br> whenever the user presses ENTER (or intro) in a textarea, since I need to send this to a pdf maker for php, which gets the text as an HTML, but if the user presses ENTER it doesnt get the break line, when I save the PDF and download it, it shows:

```
[cod][name]
```

instead of:

```
[cod]
[name]
```

What should I do ? Obviously it works if I add < br> tag manually but thats not the idea for the user

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, try using `nl2br($text)`.

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use nl2br

```
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<BODY>

<?
    echo "Initializing...<BR>";
    $txt = $_REQUEST["txt"];
    $txt = nl2br($txt);
    echo $txt;
?>

    <form name='form1' method=POST  action="text.php" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <table class="table1"><tr>
    <td>File:</td>
    <td><textarea name="txt" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type=submit></td></tr>
    </form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```